# Creation of matrix with specific attempts at the end

Tags: c#, matrix, f#

What I want to do is build a *Slay-the-Spire*-like Map. As you can see in the following image, the map is splitted in `ISteps` and `IRooms`. Each `IStep` is connected to the next one by its `IRooms`. There is no dead-end, so each `IRooms` is connected with the previous and next `ISteps`.

[image: Slay the Spire - Generated map]

Firstly, I have these two `C#` interfaces:

```
public interface IStep
{
    IRoom this[int index] { get; }
    int Size { get; }
    void Connect(IStep nextStep, int[,] matrix);
}

public interface IRoom
{
    IRoom[] NextRooms { get; }
    void Connect(IRoom nextRoom);
}
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

> - A `IStep` has a set of 3-to-5 `IRooms`.
> - I can connect two `ISteps` together, which connects the `IRooms`.
> - Each `IRoom` has at least one connection to the other `IStep` ...
> - ... and at most three
> - Connections cannot cross, but can begin from / end to the same `IRoom`

Here is what is true:

> - The minimum number of connections is equal to the larger `IStep.Size`
> - The maximum number is equal to both `IStep.Size` minus `1`
> - Each row and each column has to contains at least one `1`

I decided to represent these connections in a matrix-like display:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
This matrix says:

> - `IStep from` is connected to `IStep to`
> - `from.Size = 3` and `to.Size = 5`
> - There is a total of 6 connections
> - `from[0]` is connected to `to[0]`
> - `from[0]` is also connected to `to[1]`
> - ...
> - `from[2]` is connected to `to[4]`

---

To create this matrix, I use the following `F#` module:

```
type CellType =
| Uncertain
| Disconnected
| Connected

module Connector2D =

    let getAt array row col = Array2D.get array row col
    let setAt array row col value = Array2D.set array row col value

    let len1 array = Array2D.length1 array
    let len2 array = Array2D.length2 array

    let IsUncertain array row col = getAt array row col = Uncertain

    let IsDisconnected array row col = getAt array row col = Disconnected

    let IsConnected array row col = getAt array row col = Connected

    let filterBy predicate array =
        seq {   for i  in 0 .. len1 array - 1 do
                    for j in 0 .. len2 array - 1 do
                        if predicate array i j then
                            yield (i, j)
            }

    let ListUncertain array = array |> filterBy IsUncertain

    let ListDisconnected array = array |> filterBy IsDisconnected

    let ListConnected array = array |> filterBy IsConnected


    let CountUncertain array = ListUncertain array |> Seq.length

    let CountDisconnection array = ListDisconnected array |> Seq.length

    let CountConnection array = ListConnected array |> Seq.length

    let Disconnect array row col =
        match getAt array row col with
        | Uncertain -> 
            setAt array row col Disconnected
            true
        | Connected -> false
        | Disconnected -> true

    // Check no-cross rule
    let Connect array row col =
        if IsUncertain array row col then
            setAt array row col Connected
            // Disconnect all 'top-right' connections
            for i in 0 .. row - 1 do
                for j in col + 1 .. len2 array - 1 do
                    Disconnect array i j |> ignore
            // Disconnect all 'bottom-left' connections
            for i in row + 1 .. len1 array - 1 do
                for j in 0 .. col - 1 do
                    Disconnect array i j |> ignore
        IsConnected array row col

    // Check no-more-than-three rule
    let Create rows cols =
        let matrix = Array2D.create rows cols Uncertain
        Connect matrix 0 0 |> ignore
        Connect matrix (rows - 1) (cols - 1) |> ignore
        for i in 3 .. rows - 1 do
            Disconnect matrix i 0 |> ignore
        for i in 0 .. rows - 4 do
            Disconnect matrix i (cols - 1) |> ignore
        for j in 3 .. cols - 1 do
            Disconnect matrix 0 j |> ignore
        for j in 0 .. cols - 4 do
            Disconnect matrix (rows - 1) j |> ignore
        matrix
```

And my matrix creation method is this one:

```
public void Connect(IStep from, IStep to)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int min = Math.Max(from.Size, to.Size);
    int max = from.Size + to.Size;
    int count = rnd.Next(min, max);

    int[,] matrix = MapConnections.Create(from.Size, to.Size);
    List<int> emptyRows = Enumerable.Range(1, from.Size - 2).ToList();
    List<int> emptyCols = Enumerable.Range(1, to.Size - 2).ToList();
    while (MapConnections.CountConnection(matrix) < count)
    {
        var possibleConnections = MapConnections.ListUncertain(matrix).ToList();

        var tmp = possibleConnections.Where(pc => emptyRows.Contains(pc.Item1) && emptyCols.Contains(pc.Item2)).ToList();
        if (tmp.Count == 0)
            tmp = possibleConnections.Where(pc => emptyRows.Contains(pc.Item1) || emptyCols.Contains(pc.Item2)).ToList();
        if (tmp.Count != 0)
            possibleConnections = tmp;

        var connection = possibleConnections[rnd.Next(possibleConnections.Count)];
        MapConnections.Connect(matrix, connection.Item1, connection.Item2);
        emptyRows.Remove(connection.Item1);
        emptyCols.Remove(connection.Item2);
    }

    from.Connect(to, matrix);
}
```

---

An example of what my algorithm should do is (for 5 connections goal):

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & - & - & 0\\
- & - & - & -\\
- & - & - & -\\
0 & - & - & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & - & - & 0\\
- & - & 1 & -\\
0 & 0 & - & -\\
0 & 0 & - & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & - & - & 0\\
- & - & 1 & -\\
0 & 0 & - & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & - & 0 & 0\\
- & 1 & 1 & -\\
0 & 0 & - & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

---

My actual problem is that I can encounter this scenario (for 4 connections goal):

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & - & - & 0\\
- & - & - & -\\
- & - & - & -\\
0 & - & - & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & - & - & 0\\
- & - & 1 & -\\
0 & 0 & - & -\\
0 & 0 & - & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & - & - & 0\\
- & - & 1 & -\\
0 & 0 & - & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Finally, nothing is connected to my `to[1]`. For this very example, I could force the ones to be in the diagonal, but I want to achieve is a generic algorithm, not a *case-by-case* one.

---

If you wonder, there are all the *bad selections* for a *first-connection*, in every case (apply symmetry):

> - For 4 connections:
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>   1 & - & - & 0\\
>   - & - & * & -\\
>   - & * & - & -\\
>   0 & - & - & 1
>   \end{bmatrix}
> - For 5 connections:
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>   1 & - & - & 0\\
>   - & - & * & 0\\
>   - & - & - & -\\
>   0 & * & - & -\\
>   0 & - & - & 1
>   \end{bmatrix}
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>   1 & - & - & 0 & 0\\
>   - & - & * & * & 0\\
>   - & * & - & * & -\\
>   0 & * & * & - & -\\
>   0 & 0 & - & - & 1
>   \end{bmatrix}
> - For 6 connections:
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>   1 & - & - & 0 & 0\\
>   - & - & - & * & 0\\
>   - & - & - & - & -\\
>   0 & * & - & - & -\\
>   0 & 0 & - & - & 1
>   \end{bmatrix}

---

As asked, here are my classes and tests:

```
public class Step : IStep
{
    private IRoom[] Rooms { get; set; }
    public IRoom this[int index] { get { return Rooms[index]; } }
    public int Size { get { return Rooms.Length; } }

    public Step(IRoom first, IEnumerable<IRoom> rooms) : this(first, rooms.ToArray())
    { }
    public Step(IRoom first, params IRoom[] rooms)
    { Rooms = new IRoom[] { first }.Concat(rooms).ToArray(); }

    public void Connect(IStep nextStep, int[,] matrix)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < nextStep.Size; j++)
                if (MapConnections.IsConnected(matrix, i, j))
                    this[i].Connect(nextStep[j]);
    }
}

public /*abstract*/ class Room : IRoom
{
    public IRoom[] NextRooms { get; private set; }

    public void Connect(IRoom nextRoom)
    {
        if (NextRooms == null)
            NextRooms = new[] { nextRoom };
        else
            NextRooms = NextRooms.Concat(new[] { nextRoom }).ToArray();
    }
}

public interface IStepConnector
{
    void Connect(IStep from, IStep to);
}

public class StepConnector : IStepConnector
{
    public void Connect(IStep from, IStep to)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int min = Math.Max(from.Size, to.Size);
        int max = from.Size + to.Size;
        int count = rnd.Next(min, max);

        int[,] matrix = MapConnections.Create(from.Size, to.Size);
        List<int> emptyRows = Enumerable.Range(1, from.Size - 2).ToList();
        List<int> emptyCols = Enumerable.Range(1, to.Size - 2).ToList();
        while (MapConnections.CountConnection(matrix) < count)
        {
            var possibleConnections = MapConnections.ListUncertain(matrix).ToList();

            var tmp = possibleConnections.Where(pc => emptyRows.Contains(pc.Item1) && emptyCols.Contains(pc.Item2)).ToList();
            if (tmp.Count == 0)
                tmp = possibleConnections.Where(pc => emptyRows.Contains(pc.Item1) || emptyCols.Contains(pc.Item2)).ToList();
            if (tmp.Count != 0)
                possibleConnections = tmp;

            var connection = possibleConnections[rnd.Next(possibleConnections.Count)];
            MapConnections.Connect(matrix, connection.Item1, connection.Item2);
            emptyRows.Remove(connection.Item1);
            emptyCols.Remove(connection.Item2);
        }

        from.Connect(to, matrix);
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void CodeReviewTest()
{
    IStep from = new Step(new FightRoom(), new FightRoom(), new FightRoom(), new FightRoom(), new FightRoom());
    IStep to = new Step(new FightRoom(), new FightRoom(), new FightRoom(), new FightRoom(), new FightRoom());

    IStepConnector connector = new StepConnector();
    connector.Connect(from, to);

    List<IRoom> toRooms = new List<IRoom>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(from[i].NextRooms.Length > 0);
        for (int j = 0; j < from[i].NextRooms.Length; j++)
        {
            if (!toRooms.Contains(from[i].NextRooms[j]))
                toRooms.Add(from[i].NextRooms[j]);
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(toRooms.Contains(to[j]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. If you want a serious review of your code, I think you have to provide a little more background, context, a simple example and some full implementations of `IStep` and `IRoom`. What is it meant to be used for etc.?

Comment: @HenrikHansen Thank you! I did provide what you asked to me, tell me if this isn't enough!

Comment: Just to make things clear: does your code work as intended and are you looking for general improvements, or does it fail for specific edge-cases and you're looking to solve those cases?

Comment: Currently, my code works, because I added a `do { /*create the matrix*/ } while(/*matrix is incorrect*/);` but this solution is really ugly, so I would like to get ideas to implements the `IStepConnection.Connect` without this ugly loop. I didn't talk about this `do-while` loop because it is futile and useless information in my opinion. To answer you, my code works and I look for improvements, because it fails for specific cases that I look to solve in a single pass.

Comment: You see, to have 2 version of `Connect`, with slightly different behaviour; which is the 'right' one?

Comment: @VisualMelon Excuse-me, I built a `static class StaticRandom` that enclose a single instance of `Random`, I replaced it in one of my example but not in both. There is no difference in the algorithm! As there is no need to explain about it in the main question, I thought it was unnecessary to leave it in my post. I editted my question to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: @MaximeRecuerda I can't work out what my comment was meant to mean now (but the question looks fine)... I think I did write an answer for this somewhere, where I suggest an alternative way of generating the paths (with F# implementation), but I wasn't very happy with it. I might have another look today and post it in whatever shape it is in.

Comment: @VisualMelon I indeed post another topic about my F# code, which I didn't update in this topic. Nevertheless, before your comment (and my edit) there was two different implementations of the `void Connect(IStep from, IStep to)` method. I will update the F# code in here as well, as my other post is now answered.

Comment: Go for it; this was a fun question to review, and it would be nice to get an answer from somebody who is better at F# than I am.

Comment: @VisualMelon Oh but **this** post is not about F# part, the related post is [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/207497/connect-elements-of-a-list-to-elements-of-an-other-list-using-a-two-dim-array)

Comment: Not sure a single pass solution is possible, or simple enough. I would tackle this problem as a constraint satisfaction problem (CSP). There are algorithms, like dancing links (DLX) to solve such problems with statistically a smaller amount of passes than a brute force.